# What is the line orthogonal to $3x - 4y - 12=0$ and passes $(-3,2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> What is the line orthogonal to $3x - 4y - 12=0$ and passes $(-3,2)$

Orthogonal to 3x - 4y - 12

$y = (-4/3 )x + c$

Passes through 3,2

$c=-2$

So

$y= (-4/3) x - 2$

But the answer is: $ 2/3 x + 1/2 y + 1 = 0$.

Comment: Fine.Option.Line through a given point (x_0,y_0), arbitrary m: y-y_0=m(x-x_0); here: y-2=m(x+3), with m=-4/3.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you got and the given one are equivalent. Clearing fractions in the given one gives $$4x+3y+6=0,$$ and rearranging gives $$y=-4x/3-6/3=-\frac43x-2,$$ which is the form in which yours is presented.

Answer (score 0):

I like the following way:
$$y-2=-\frac{4}{3}(x+3)$$ or
$$y=-\frac{4}{3}x-2$$ and we got the same result.

It's also
$$\frac{4}{3}x+y+2=0$$ or
$$\frac{2}{3}x+\frac{1}{2}y+1=0$$

Comment: But the answer is 2/3 x + 1/2 y + 1 = 0

Comment: @Lifeforbetter They are the same.

Comment: Oh, they just divided by 2..

Comment: Can down-voter explain us, why did you do it?